# Firebase delete, bolt permission configuration

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I'm am trying to delete a record from firebase with `firebase.remove()` like so:

```
// inside deleteGame function
const promiseDeleteGame = firebase.child(`games/${game.id}`).remove();
return Observable.from(promise)
  .mapTo(deleteGameDone(game))
  .catch(error => Observable.of(deleteGameFailure(error)));
```

My `rules.bolt` file is configured like so:

```
isOwner(gameId) { auth.uid == root.games[gameId].ownerId }

path games/{gameId} is Game { 
  read() { true }
  create() { true }
  update() { true }
  delete() { isOwner(gameId) }
}
```

I always get the error: `set at /games/{gameId} failed: permission_denied.`

Is the problem that I can't delete a record since that given record that I'm trying to delete includes the property `ownerId`, which should give me the permission to delete the record?

Or maybe because the `Game` object has a property called `registrations` which is a map of userId's and their info and I don't have permissions to update the `registrations` property?

Answer (score 1):

I am new to firebase bolt.
I would suggest you to use following syntax.

```
delete() { auth != null && auth.uid == prior(this).ownerId }
```